# The modal verb 'will' in reporting

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

M. Hewings in his book *Advanced Grammar In Use* explains that the modal verb **will** in the original statement, suggestion, etc. can be either changed into **would** or unchanged i.e. still **will** when it's used for **existing** or **future** situations and **past tense verb** in reporting clause.

In the exercise, however, the usage of the modal verb **will** seems to be changed into **would**. The sentence is shown below

> **Underline the more approproate verb. If both are possible, underline them both**
>
> 4. Inge promised that she *will / would* be at home by nine, so I
>    phoned her shortly after that.

The answer key says the only possibility is **would**, that means using **will** won't appropriate, but doesn't it contradict with the explanation above that I can use either **will** or **would**? Or is it possibly that the situation in the sentence is neither existing nor future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "*promised*" is a past tense verb in a reporting clause. It is not used for an existing or future situation. So this sentence follows the book's rules.